# Why does it take so long for a driver command to run on PayPal's sandbox website

Tags: selenium, paypal

When I am redirected to Paypal's sandbox site my java commands take forever to execute.  The simplest of commands take upwards of 5 minutes to execute.  Anyone know how I can speed up the process?

Here is an example command, quite simple:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("login_email")).sendKeys("email@email.com");
```

Or on https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=O4woPh5v7Y9g0efhaNimBqKCK1_ahbD3q-PcVGfff2kZaeCD6k3NBaSH10C&dispatch=50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b08198dbcfd9e439351aac748846c5173df4f4

```
driver.findElement(By.id("continueBabySlider")).click();
```

POM:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.33.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.33.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.32.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Needs more information. What browser? What version of that browser? What version of Selenium? Different result in other browsers? Reproducible on another machine? (Physical or virtual).

Comment: I added the pom below.  It is reproducible on other physical machines.   Have not tried on a virtual machine.

Comment: It looks like paypal is taking forever to load the entire page.  Is there a way to execute command before a page fully loads?